# Assign AD Group to Azure AD Application Role using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, user-roles

I have no problem adding a user to a role using

https://graph.windows.net/{TenantId}/users/{UserId}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.5

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
  id = roleId,
  principalDisplayName = userEmail,
  principalId = userId,
  principalType = "User",
  resourceId = servicePrincipalId
});
```

But this is not working for groups by changing:

https://graph.windows.net/{TenantId}/groups/{GroupId}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.5

```
principalDisplayName = GroupDisplayName,
principalId = groupId,
principalType = "Group"
```

Also tried without the principalDisplayName

I am receiving "Bad Request" and in Fiddler "One or more properties are invalid." with no extra information.

Comment: Do you have group-based role assignment available in the tenant?

Comment: Correct that solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Can you login to azure portal with your tenant credential and check if you can assign AAD group to role? It's most likely related to your permission

Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications -> Find your application -> Users and Groups -> Add User

Comment: Correct that solved the issue, the app has no permission to add groups to role.

$clientId = '{appClientId}'
$webApp = Get-MsolServicePrincipal –AppPrincipalId $clientId
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName "Company Administrator" -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleMemberObjectId $webApp.ObjectId

Comment: And yes using the interface I can add groups to the roles.